# Multisession support in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra

I have a (very) basic Sinatra program that does this:

```
get '/loginbasic' do
   erb :login_basic
end #get /loginbasic


post '/generatetoken' do
  @@username = params[:username]
  @@password = params[:password]
  @@token = function(@@username, @@password)
end #post /generatetoken


get '/token' do
  erb :token, :locals => {'username' => @@username, 'serviceroot' =>  @@serviceroot, 'token' => @@token}
end #/token
```

Very straightforward.

I ask for username and password (/loginbasic)
loginbasic posts to /generatetoken which then generate a token (with a function whatever)
The user can then point to /token to read its token.

It works fine.

Problem is that it's single session, in the sense that if I point to /token from another laptop, it shows the token of the user that entered id / password and generated the token.

It appears that Sinatra supports multisessions (http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions) but I am not sure how to implement this from a code perspective. What I would like to do is that if a user connects to /token and he/she doesn't have a generated token, he/she either gets an error (or much better yet it gets redirected to /loginbasic).

How could I lift my code to make that happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at Sinatra recipes. There's an article there about authentication: http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/middleware/rack_auth_basic_and_digest?#article

Comment: Thanks @w0lf. I am not sure I am able to follow that link. I am not even sure he is trying to do what I am trying to do (maybe he is). A colleague of mine pointed me to this other post (that I failed googling) that has enough into that allowed me to tweak the code the way I needed: https://gist.github.com/amscotti/1384524

Answer (score 0):

I was able to tweak the code this way and it seems to be working:

```
get '/loginbasic' do
  erb :login_basic
end #get /loginbasic


post '/generatetoken' do
  session[:@@username] = params[:username]
  session[:@@password] = params[:password]
  session[:@@token] = function(session[:@@username], session[:@@password])
end #post /generatetoken


get '/token' do
  erb :token, :locals => {'username' => session[:@@username], 'serviceroot' => @@serviceroot, 'token' => session[:@@token]}
end #/token
```